# Delphi 10.2: Using Local SQL with Firedac Memory Tables

Tags: sql, delphi, firedac, memory-table

How can I use Firedac LocalSQL with FDMemtable? Is there any working example available?

According to the [Embarcadero DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Local_SQL_(FireDAC)) I set up a local connection (using SQLite driver), a LocalSQL component and connected some Firedac memory tables to it. Then I connected a FDQuery and try to query the memory tables. But the query always returns "table xyz not known" even if I set an explicit dataset name for the memory table in the localSQL dataset collection.

I suspect that I miss something fundamental that is not contained in the Embarcadero docs. If anyone has ever got this up and running I would be grateful for some tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code I wrote for an answer here a while ago, which is a self-contained example of using `LocalSQL`, tested in D10.2 (Seattle).  It should suffice to get you going.  Istr that the key to getting it working was a comment somewhere in the EMBA docs that FD's LocalSQL is based on Sqlite, as you've noted.

```
procedure TForm3.CopyData2;
begin
  DataSource2.DataSet := FDQuery1;

  FDConnection1.DriverName := 'SQLite';
  FDConnection1.Connected := True;

  FDLocalSQL1.Connection := FDConnection1;
  FDLocalSQL1.DataSets.Add(FDMemTable1);

  FDLocalSQL1.Active := True;

  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from FDMemTable1 order by ID limit 5';
  FDQuery1.Active := True;

  FDMemTable1.Close;
  FDMemTable1.Data := FDQuery1.Data;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
  MS : TMemoryStream;
begin
  FDMemTable1.CreateDataSet;
  for i := 1 to 10 do
    FDMemTable1.InsertRecord([i, 'Row:' + IntToStr(i), 10000 - i]);
  FDMemTable1.First;

  //  Following is to try to reproduce problem loading from stream
  //  noted by the OP, but works fine
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    FDMemTable1.SaveToStream(MS, sfBinary);
    MS.Position := 0;
    FDMemTable1.LoadFromStream(MS, sfBinary);
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As you can see, you can refer in the SQL to an existing FireDAC dataset simply by using its component name.

Comment: Thanks, that was exacly what I did with one difference: I loaded the memtables from a stream. They seem to loose their names when loaded from stream because if I added records manually it worked. So I just set the names again after loading from a stream everything works fine. You pointed me into the directoion adding records in code so I accept your answer!

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit odd.  I've updated my answer so that the FDMemtable is saved to a memory stream during the FormCreate and reloaded from it, but this works fine and does not affect the LocalSql operations.